# How to add taxonomy in drupal; not a vocabulary?

Tags: php, drupal, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms, vocabulary

I am following drupal documentation. In [chapter 6.5](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/structure-taxonomy.html), they explain how *taxonomy* is different from *vocabulary*. In this page it is suggested that on a website, which list *farmers* and *recipes* list by them, we should have a taxonomy for the ingredients of recipes:

> the farmers market website could use an **ingredients taxonomy** to classify recipes.

So lets say I have a taxonomy `ingredients` with its terms as `red tomato, green tomato, small tomato, cumin, carrot, eggplant, salt, pepper`. Also the documentation mentions:

> ...a set of terms is known as a vocabulary ...

So in my case `red tomato, green tomato` and `small tomato` represent one vocabulary.

In the next documentation page [chapter 6.6](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/structure-taxonomy-setup.html), it says:

> Create an **Ingredients vocabulary**

No no no, so my question is how do I create an Ingredients taxonomy; not an Ingredients vocabulary? Even in drupal admin panel I see only the option to create vocabulary under `structure>taxonomy`.

Answer (score 2):

> the farmers market website could use an **ingredients taxonomy** to classify recipes.

> Create an Ingredients vocabulary

Maybe it was a wording error in the Drupal documentation. Actually `taxonomy` is an entity type, which is already built by Drupal core. So you'll never have to create it. What you need to do is create a `vocabulary` which is a set of `taxonomy terms` of the same type used to classify something.

Specifically, in your case, **ingredients** is a `vocabulary`, and **red tomato**, **green tomato**, **small tomato**,... are `taxonomy terms`

Comment: Where can I find the definition of _taxonomy_? In my opinion _ingredients_ is a texonomy with two vocabularies _tomato: red tomato, green tomato, small tomato_ and _others: cumin, carrot, eggplant, salt, pepper_

Comment: @user31782 A taxonomy is a classification of terms and we classify terms according to a _vocabulary_ (or lexical field). What is confusing you is the (possible) vocabulary's hierarchy. All ingredients of any recipe can be classified under a single vocabulary that you might preferably want to call _ingredients_ : ie. to list the ingredients of a given recipe, you will refer to this vocabulary, not _tomato_ nor _others_. But nothing prevents having a hierarchical structure where you have the vocabularies _tomato_ and _others_ under _ingredients_, each with their respective subset of ingredients.

Comment: @EricLavault Does `taxonomy - vocabulary` follow the `class - object` analogy? Sounds like `ingredient` is a class and the _terms_ are the objects of that class and then collection of terms(objects) is vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

In English, a term can have different meaning based on perspective, with that said, the Drupal meaning of taxonomy is as follow.

Taxonomy = vocabularies containing terms.

Ingredients taxonomy = Ingredients Vocabulary (containing) -> Red Tomato, Cumin......

Mostly the way you classify your information.

Please refer to this https://drupalize.me/topic/taxonomy a reupdated source for Drupal topics.